# Using EF with existing database and domain/object model which is not 1:1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first

First of all: I'm an EF-newbie, and this is just to test the capabilities of EF, and to see how it fits into an environment which is already set in terms of database tables and object model - and when these two models do not map 1:1 in terms of class names/table names and attribute names/column names, and even the number of tables and classes. Please keep "test the capabilities" in mind should you feel the urge to reply: "EF is not meant to be used that way". Thanks! :)

Consider the following scenario.

I have three database tables:

```
|----------------|       |-------------|       |-----------------|
|   MessageLog   | >---1 |   Message   | 1---< |   MessageText   |
|----------------|       |-------------|       |-----------------|
| logId          |       | messageId   |       | messageId       |
| messageId      |       | type        |       | languageCode    |
| from           |       | ...         |       | text1           |
| to             |       |-------------|       | text2           |
| ...            |                             | ...             |
|----------------|                             |-----------------|
```

Which I want to map to two classes:

```
|--------------------|       |----------------------------|
|   ServiceMessage   |<-\    |   ServiceMessageInstance   |
|--------------------|  |    |----------------------------|
| Id: string         |  |    | Id: string                 |
| LanguageCode: str. |  \----| Message: ServiceMessage    |
| Text1: string      |       | From: DateTime             |
| Text2: string      |       | To: DateTime               |
| Type: MessageType  |       |----------------------------|
|--------------------|
```

ServiceMessage objects are comprised of a row from the Message table (with **messageId** as key) and a row from the MessageText table (with **messageId** and **languageCode** as keys).

ServiceMessageInstance is easier: it has a reference to a ServiceMessage object, and some additional attributes.

I have played a bit with EF, and done a lot of googling, but I have not found the answer to my question: How can I make this happen with EF? Which approach should I take? Can I do this with the EDMX designer? DbContext.OnModelCreating?

I realise that this might be a bit too "wide" a question, but I would appreciate any pointers!

Thanks.

BR,
Herms

Comment: +1 for the ASCII-Style object/database model :D

Comment: It's a merge of entity splitting and TPH inheritance (where `languageCode` serves as a discriminator). I don't think that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Which way to go question:-)  Its explained well here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

To assist you you can also install the **Entity Framework powertools.**

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

There is a nice option to **reverse engineer code first** from a DB.
Make a new Project. Then on the project Right Click , the context menu should offer
[image]

You should see code added to your project.  This can be useful to review. Then deleted the temp project. after taking useful parts for your own code.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth i haven't actually tried to this because i didn't come across a situation that forced me to do so, never the less i remember that when i was reading "[Programming Entity Framework DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969)" i came across a section in chapter 5 to be exact called "Mapping a Single Entity Across Multiple Tables" which i think does exactly what you want.
**NOTES**

- The above mentioned feature called **"Entity Splitting"** uses entity framework code first but i assume (*not sure*) that it is possible with other entity framework mythologies as well.
- You can't enable it via Data Annotations, instead you will have to configure it with Fluent API.
- To do that you need to use the **[Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679141%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)** function.
- There is also a feature that goes in the other direction too, and it allows you to map multiple entities to a single table.